# Grouping and extraction unique items based on columns in dataframes?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, plot, grouping

I have a dataframe as follows:

mydata:

```
Id, date
X1, 2015,01
X2, 2015,02
X2, 2015,02
X3, 2015,03
X3, 2015,03
X4, 2015,03
X4, 2015,03
X5, 2015,05
X6, 2015,05
X7, 2015,05
```

From this dataframe, I want to extract two lists for plotting purpose. In the first list “x_labels” I would like to have the unique dates, and in the second list “y_values” I want to have the number of unique Ids which have the same date. I could extract the first list by the following code:

```
x= mydata.groupby(by=[date],as_index=False)
x_labels=list(x.size().reset_index([0])[date'])
```

So, the output is:

```
x_labels=[‘2015,01’, ‘2015,02’, ‘2015,03’, ‘2015,05’]
```

But, I could not extract the second list (`y_values`). The desired the list should be like this:

```
y_values=[1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.nunique` gives both `x_values` and `y_values`:

```
d = df.groupby('date')['Id'].nunique()
print(d)
```

Output:

```
date
2015,01    1
2015,02    1
2015,03    2
2015,05    3
Name: Id, dtype: int64
```

You can extract into variables you want:

```
x_values, y_values = list(d.index), list(d.values)
x_values
# ['2015,01', '2015,02', '2015,03', '2015,05']
y_values
# [1, 1, 2, 3]
```